# Not able to display html page(stored in a variable) in the .hbs file

Tags: html, node.js, express, handlebars.js, hbs

Not able to display output in form of html table when rendered to the .hbs file.
When I write res.send() it displays in the HTML format that I wanted to show but when I do res.render it does not display it in the HTML format instead it also shows my table and row tags in the output

```
app.get('/data/search/title', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('form_process_title', { name: 'Form Title' });
});
```

When I hit the above url data/search/title it takes me to the form_process_title.hbs file which is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to {{ name }} page</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="/form_route_title">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <p>{{ans}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

After submitting the form I will get redirected to the below route

```
app.post('/form_route_title', function (req, res, next) {
  var ans = "<table border = 3>";
  ans += "<tr>";
  ans += "<td>" + "Title" + "</td>";
  ans += "<td>" + "ISBN" + "</td>";
  ans += "<td>" + "Description" + "</td>" + "</tr>";

  var count = 0;
  try {
    // console.log(req.body.title);
    let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('myData.json'));
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].title.includes(req.body.title)) {
        ans += "<tr>";
        count++;
        ans += "<td>" + data[i].title + "</td>";
        ans += "<td>" + data[i].isbn + "</td>";
        ans += "<td>" + data[i].shortDescription + "</td>";
        ans += "</tr>";
      }
    }
    ans += "</table>";
    console.log("Count = " + count);
    res.render('form_process_title', { name: 'Form Title', ans: ans });
    //res.send(ans);
  }
  catch {
    res.render('form_process_title', { name: 'Form Title', ans: "Sorry the data does not exist" });
    //res.send("Sorry the data at this index does not exist")
  }
});
```

When I do res.send(ans) it works perfectly but I want it to work in the below step -
res.render('form_process_title', { name: 'Form Title', ans: ans });

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuTVo.png)

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSkUs.png)

From the above images you can see that I am not getting the desired output.

I am expecting the output to be displayed in the HTML table format not just the tags.

Comment: The short answer is that Handlebars is escaping the HTML in `ans`, so replace `<p>{{ans}}</p>` with `{{{ans}}}` - the triple mustaches tell Handlebars not to HTML-escape. But I would advise you not to put all of that table HTML into a variable. HTML belongs in your Handlebars templates.

Comment: Thank you so much, the output is now coming in HTML format